# NaN result when summing two tensors which individually are both real numbers

Tags: python, tensorflow, nan

So I've been playing with this interesting application of tensorflow: [TensorKart](http://kevinhughes.ca/blog/tensor-kart)

The full source code is here: https://github.com/kevinhughes27/TensorKart

I'm getting a NaN result in my loss calculation and it's totally stumped me. The problem lies in this line of code:

```
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(model.y_, model.y))) + tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in train_vars]) * L2NormConst
```

When I evaluate the first part:

```
tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(model.y_, model.y)))
```

I get values around 0.8
When I evaluate the second part:

```
tf.add_n([tf.nn.l2_loss(v) for v in train_vars]) * L2NormConst
```

I get values around 3.1

BUT when I sum the two parts I get NaN?!?!

I've checked the shape and types and they both come back as: Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(0,), dtype=int32)

Things that I have tried: using tf.reduce_sum instead of tf.add_n, casting them to tf.float32, summing them with tf.add....

Does anyone have any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after having gone through every operation leading up to the calculation of the loss value, it turns out there were NaN values in my input data. Converting them to zero resolved the issue of getting a NaN result in the final loss value calculation.

What I haven't figured out till now is why I was only getting an error at the point I sum the two parts of the loss value but not while calculating the parts individually.

Utterly bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar problem. It took me some time to figure this out.

There is one possibility that one of your inputs contains `inf` or `-inf`. And after some other operations, `nan` occurs. So if you only check if inputs contain `nan`, that is not enough. You should possibly check if they contain `inf` or `-inf`.

I will recommend using `tf.math.is_finite` to check if inputs contain `inf`, `-inf`, and `nan`. Here is the example,

```
tf.reduce_any(~tf.math.is_finite(x))
```

where `x` is your input.